# Преобразование данных в нужный формат

Tags: javascript

есть данные вида

```
const data = [{
    name: "country",
    data: [{
        name: "city1",
        count: 74,
      },
      {
        name: "city2",
        count: 4,
      },
      {
        name: "city3",
        count: 6,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "country2",
    data: [{
        name: "city2",
        count: 12,
      },
      {
        name: "city3",
        count: 16,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

мне их надо преобразовать в другой формат

```
[
  {
    "name": "country",
    "city1": {
      "name": "city1",
      "count": 74
    },
    "city2": {
      "name": "city2",
      "count": 4
    },
    "city3": {
      "name": "city3",
      "count": 6
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "country2",
    "city2": {
      "name": "city2",
      "count": 12
    },
    "city3": {
      "name": "city3",
      "count": 16
    }
  }
]
```

мое решение

```js
let result = [];
data.map((country) => {
  let obj = {
    name: country.name
  }
  country.data.map((city, index) => {
    obj[city.name] = city
  })
  result.push(obj)
})

console.log(result)
```

Вопрос заключается в том как можно сделать такое преобразование красивее и более правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) уже возвращает массив, нет нужды его отдельно создавать и вручную заполнять
2. для свертки массива `.data` в объект можно использовать [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
const data = [{
    name: "country",
    data: [{
        name: "city1",
        count: 74,
      },
      {
        name: "city2",
        count: 4,
      },
      {
        name: "city3",
        count: 6,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "country2",
    data: [{
        name: "city2",
        count: 12,
      },
      {
        name: "city3",
        count: 16,
      }
    ]
  }
]

let result = data.map((country) => country.data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {
  name: country.name
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант с reduce.